# How can I save strings from different alphabets to SQL?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, alphabet

I am developing a backend project for my mobile apps. I have users from Europa, China, Israel, ... on my app. The app needs users' info like name.
I have a "name" column on the "users" table on SQL.
I want to save the names of all users from different alphabets in the same table. I want to save all users' names on the same table via a different alphabet but I don't know what should I do about this issue.

When I try to save users' name via API that my developed, the name saving like "???? ????"

[image]

When I try to save users' name via phpMyAdmin I get the following error

[image]

**Note**: I am new on the backend & server & SQL sides, I would be very grateful if you could clearly explain what I need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **Solution:**

I was using MySQL version 5.7. The problem was solved when I upgrade MySQL version to 8.0

I used the following page for the version update process.

[**Link**](https://www.javacodemonk.com/upgrade-mysql-from-5-7-to-8-on-ubuntu-18-04-bd9b5e46)